# What are the origins of the word Hebrew?

Tags: etymology, hebrew

I have read that this word may derive from an Egyptian decree issued by Pharoah Merueptah (1224 which referred to the hebrew word *'habitu'* (type of slave) who carry stones for the great pylon of the great city of Rameses'.

But what is the actual etymology?

Comment: I’ve nothing to add to Otavio’s answer, but I’d love to know who offered the _habitu_ etymology!

Comment: Note that `habitu`'s meaning is actually "look", used as an imperative for many.

Comment: I think you may mean "habiru" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habiru). If so, the identification of the Habiru with the Hebrews is far from certain.

Answer (score 9):

From Chambers Dictionary 11th Ed.:

> ORIGIN: OFr *Ebreu* and L *Hebraeus*, from Gr *Hebraios*, from Aramaic *ʻebrai* (Heb *ʻibrī*), literally, one from the other side (of the Euphrates)

From Oxford English Dictionary 2nd. Ed.:

> ME. *Ebreu*, a. OF. *Ebreu*, *Ebrieu* (nom. *Ebreus*, 12th c. in Hatz.-Darm.), ad. med.L. *Ebrę̄us* for cl.L. *Hebræus*, a. Gr. *Ἑβραῖος*, f. Aramaic ‭*ﻋebrai*, corresp. to Heb. ‭*ﻋibrī* ‘a Hebrew’, lit. ‘one from the other side (of the river)’;

From [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=hebrew):

> late O.E., from O.Fr. *Ebreu*, from L. *Hebraeus*, from Gk. *Hebraios*, from Aramaic *'ebhrai*, corresponding to Heb. *'ibhri* "an Israelite," lit. "one from the other side," in reference to the River Euphrates, or perhaps simply signifying "immigrant;" from *'ebher* "region on the other or opposite side." The noun is c.1200, "the Hebrew language;" late 14c. of persons, originally "a biblical Jew, Israelite."

From Collins English Dictionary:

> [from Old French *Ebreu*, from Latin *Hebraeus*, from Greek *Hebraios*, from Aramaic *`ibhray*, from Hebrew *`ibhrī* one from beyond (the river)]

Comment: Is it cognate with the word Eupharates?

Comment: @Anixx "Old Persian Ufratu, itself from Elamite or Sumerian, of unknown meaning"

Comment: "one from the other side (of the Euphrates)" since Abraham was perceived as coming from east of the Euphrates?

Answer (score 5):

http://www.abarim-publications.com/Meaning/Hebrew.html#.UA7JVmGwzW4

> The word Hebrew comes from the verb  (עבר) meaning to pass over,
>   through, take away. The first application of this word is in the name
>   Eber. The second application is in the first occurrence of the word עברי,
>   Hebrew in Genesis 14:13, where Abram is called Hebrew. The first case
>   of narrative use of this verb is in the enigmatic cadaver vision of
>   Genesis 15:17, "...there appeared a smoking furnace and a flaming
>   torch that passed between these parts."

Answer (score -4):

The word for "Hebrew" in Hebrew is

> עברית

pronounced

> eev-rit

It's easy to see how the various language variations could emerge from there (i.e. V changing to B, adding an H at the beginning)

Comment: It is actually the other way around: original /b/ changed to /v/.